# How do I test abstract classes in C++ using the Google Test framework?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, abstract, googletest

I use the [Google Test](https://github.com/google/googletest) framework to write unit tests for C++ code. Among other tests, I want to test the correct construction of objects of different classes that are all derived from one abstract class. Let's start with the abstract class:

```
class AbstractClass
{
    public:
        virtual ~AbstractClass() = default;
        std::string getName() const { return name_; }
        std::string toString() const { return toStringImpl(); }

    protected:
        AbstractClass(std::string name) : name_(name) {}

    private:
        virtual std::string toStringImpl() const = 0;
        std::string name_;
};
```

It has the function `getName()` that is implemented by the abstract class itsself. And it has a `toString()` function whose implementation is delegated to the derived classes by the private pure virtual function `toStringImpl()`. `toString()` is not much of interest here, but its concept makes this class abstract.

I have two derived conctrete classes as follows:

```
class ConcreteClassA : public AbstractClass
{
    public:
        ConcreteClassA(std::string name) : AbstractClass(name) {}
    private:
        virtual std::string toStringImpl() const override { return ""; }
};

class ConcreteClassB : public AbstractClass
{
    public:
        ConcreteClassB(std::string name) : AbstractClass(name) {}
    private:
        virtual std::string toStringImpl() const override { return ""; }
};
```

Nothing special, just the fact that the constructor of the abstract class is called during the construction of these concrete classes.

If I want to test the correct construction, I can of course write all tests for all derived classes like in the following example where I include tests for functionalities of the abstract class:

```
class ConcreteClassATests : public ::testing::Test
{};

TEST_F(ConcreteClassATests, constructionSuccessful)
{
    ConcreteClassA a {"TestA"};
    ASSERT_EQ(a.getName(), "TestA");
}

class ConcreteClassBTests : public ::testing::Test
{};

TEST_F(ConcreteClassBTests, constructionSuccessful)
{
    ConcreteClassB b {"TestB"};
    ASSERT_EQ(b.getName(), "TestB");
}
```

Given *m* derived classes and *n* tests for content of the abstract class, this will result in *m*n* handwritten tests. I think this should be solved with *n* handwritten tests (resulting either in *n* or *m*n* executed tests).

I already read about [Value-Parameterized Abstract Tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#creating-value-parameterized-abstract-tests) which sound promising and also about [Typed Tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#typed-tests), but it looks like this would only apply to testing functions that receive input and output a result. I am not sure if those concepts can be applied to test for a correct construction of objects.

So, can someone tell me if it is somehow possible to define the test for an "abstract feature" only once?

---

To reproduce and run my example, all snippets can be put together into one source file. Just add the following two lines on top and link against `gmock_main` and `pthread`:

```
#include <string>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
```

Comment: I think the root of the problem is what are are you trying to test with your abstract `class`?  The example you provided only has two exposed member functions: `getName` and `toString`.  The only part I'd argue requires testing is that `toString` invokes `toStringImpl`, which you can get by writing a `class` that inherits from `AbstractClass` directly in your test.

Comment: @StephenNewell Thx, for looking into it! I tried to post a minimal reproducible example. The abstract class and the derived classes may be larger and more complex, of course. With my testing, I want to make sure, that whenever any derived class is instantiated, the work, that is done by the contructor of the abstract class, is done correctly. Imagine I would add a feature to the constructor of `AbstractClass` that it throws an exception for empty strings. Right now, I have to write additional tests for each concrete class to assert that an exception is thrown. But I want to do it only once :-)

Comment: It depends if you test derived classes as black box, or by knowing they inherit from AbstractClass. Btw, you can still create function and then `CheckAbstractClass (ConcreteClassB, "TestB"/*..*/);`.